# Remember Cookie After Restarting browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use the code below, with cookies, to allow my site visitors to change the font size of my site. Everything works fine; the cookies are remembered when I refresh/close the page. However, they are lost once I restart the browser. Is there a way to adjust the cookie code below to be remembered after restarting the browser? Thanks for any help. (I know close to nothing about jquery, and I found this code online and I have adjusted it to my needs but I need help with the cookies.)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".button-f16").click(function() {
    $("p").addClass("f16").removeClass("f22");
    $.removeCookie('cookief22');
    $.cookie("cookief16", $(".button-f16").hasClass('f16'));
  });
  if ($.cookie("cookief16") == "true") {
    $("p").addClass("f16").removeClass("f22");
  }
});
  
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".button-f22").click(function() {
    $("p").addClass("f22").removeClass("f16");
    $.removeCookie('cookief16');
    $.cookie("cookief22", $(".button-f22").hasClass('f22'));
  });
  if ($.cookie("cookief22") == "true") {
    $("p").addClass("f22").removeClass("f16");
  }
});


.f22 {
  font-size: 22px;
} 
.f16 {
  font-size: 16px;
}  

<p class="button-f16">16px font</p>
<p class="button-f22">22px font</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not giving it an expire time, it's not a cookie.
It's called a session.
A session expires when you close the browser.
Set an expiration time for it, and you should be fine.

> $.cookie("test", 1, { expires : 10 });

note that the 'expires: 10' means 10 days.

Comment: Parsa, excuse my ignorance, but where do I put the code?

Comment: Simply add it where you are creating you cookie right now. Instead of just making a cookie with a 'value' and 'key', make a cookie with 'key', 'value' and 'expire time'.
I am not familiar with jQuery so I can't point it out in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You dont set time of expires
example :

```
$.cookie('name', 'value', { expires: 7 });
```